# Publishing a novel idea without experiments and results

Tags: publications, publishability, online-resource

I wrote a technical paper on a novel idea related to internet technologies. However, I don't have resources to conduct large scale experiment. Also, the numerical results cannot be consider as well. 
In the given situation is it wise to publish the idea paper in a low quality journal or submit it on arxiv?

Comment: It will likely just get lost in the noise either way. Interesting ideas need some validation.

Comment: @Buffy for validation I need large scale experiment. I was thinking to share with resourceful professors but I am not sure if it is a good idea.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Ideas are like ...opinions...: everyone has one.

"Just an idea" is not research, and is not typically publishable. An idea based on a substantial compilation of existing research may be publishable, in which case the added value is the synthesis. I see this semi-frequently in my field (which is different from yours), but these types of "ideas papers" typically have other value to other readers in that they are written from the perspective of experts in the field. It's not a way to enter the field. They also double as review articles, but I somewhat doubt your technical paper serves as a review.

Publishable in this context means being able to put it somewhere that people will see value in it. Of course you can always pay someone to publish it, but that doesn't really have value.

Comment: Thank you Bryan! when I am saying Idea it is in detail description of system with mathematical representations and discussion on their use within exiting system. However, its all a theory! In computer science these kind of paper exist but came from experience and well known researchers. I don't have such kind of profile, so I need validity.